# dplyr::mutate: Puzzling outcome of sum()

Tags: r, dplyr

upon learning some data science tools in R, I stumbled upon the following "error":
(this is code from chapter 12 of "R for Data Science" by Wickham & Grolemund):

```
library(forcats)
library(tidyverse)

by_age <- gss_cat %>% 
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>% 
  group_by(age, marital) %>% 
  count() %>%  
  mutate(prop= n/sum(n))
```

In contrast to the statement in the book, I incorrectly get a prop column containing only 1 (e.g. 100%) for each row.
Now, I have tried to modify this example and got the following additional information:

1. If I am more explicit via calling `base::sum` instead of `sum` the error still remains
2. If I compute the sum outside of the pipe in an extra statement  and then use the computed number in the statement (i.e. instead of `n/sum(n)` -> n/21407), I get the correct proportions.

Can anyone maybe help me and explain the cause of the problem?

Thank you for any help and advices!

```
R-Version 4.2.1. RStudio: "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (7872775e, 2022-07-22) for Ubuntu Bionic
```

Comment: maybe it is a grouping issues? I.e. the `group_by()` distorts the sum you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it may be necessary to `ungroup()` the data.frame before calculating prop and other variables.

Note that n and sum_n are the same here, leading to prop = 1:

```r
library(forcats)
library(tidyverse)

options(scipen = 999) # This makes it easy to inspect

gss_cat %>% 
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>% 
  group_by(age, marital) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  mutate(
    n = n,
    sum_n = sum(n),
    prop= n/sum(n)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

#     age       marital   n sum_n prop
# 1    18 Never married  89    89    1
# 2    18       Married   2     2    1
# 3    19 Never married 234   234    1
# 4    19      Divorced   3     3    1
# 5    19       Widowed   1     1    1
# 6    19       Married  11    11    1
# 7    20 Never married 227   227    1
# 8    20     Separated   1     1    1
# 9    20      Divorced   2     2    1
# 10   20       Married  21    21    1
```

But after using `ungroup()` first it gives the correct proportion:

```r
gss_cat %>% 
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>% 
  group_by(age, marital) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(
    n = n,
    sum_n = sum(n),
    prop= n/sum(n)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

#     age       marital   n sum_n          prop
# 1    18 Never married  89 21407 0.00415751857
# 2    18       Married   2 21407 0.00009342738
# 3    19 Never married 234 21407 0.01093100388
# 4    19      Divorced   3 21407 0.00014014108
# 5    19       Widowed   1 21407 0.00004671369
# 6    19       Married  11 21407 0.00051385061
# 7    20 Never married 227 21407 0.01060400803
# 8    20     Separated   1 21407 0.00004671369
# 9    20      Divorced   2 21407 0.00009342738
# 10   20       Married  21 21407 0.00098098753
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally forgot about the group statement in between - embarrasing! This solved my question.

Answer (score 0):

1. `base::sum()` and `sum()` are equal. `<library name>::` is used to find a function inside the specific library without loading the whole library. However, `base` is loaded by default, so `sum()` function is already loaded from there.
2. What are you doing in this code is:

a. Filter non-NaN values (removing missings)

b. Grouping all the rows by age and marital value. **So all the following operations will be done based in these groups.**

c. `count()` returns the number of samples per these groups. So it is like writting `count(age, marital)`.

d. You are creating a new variable based on `n` value for the sample and the `sum(n)` for values in that group which returns 1 because you have summarised the groups with `count()`.

If you want to know the proportion of every group / sum of all n values, **you should `ungroup()` the values before calling `mutate()`**. Or, actually, **you don't need to `group_by` the data**:

```
by_age <- gss_cat %>% filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
  count(age, marital) %>%  mutate(prop= n/sum(n))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 351 × 4
     age marital           n      prop
   <int> <fct>         <int>     <dbl>
 1    18 Never married    89 0.00416  
 2    18 Married           2 0.0000934
 3    19 Never married   234 0.0109   
 4    19 Divorced          3 0.000140 
 5    19 Widowed           1 0.0000467
 6    19 Married          11 0.000514 
 7    20 Never married   227 0.0106   
 8    20 Separated         1 0.0000467
 9    20 Divorced          2 0.0000934
10    20 Married          21 0.000981 
# … with 341 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally forgot about the group statement in between - embarrasing! This solved my question.

Comment: No problem. A good suggestion when someone is learning to use `tidyverse` and `dplyr` is to stop to understand every statement and operation. If you thing this was helpful press the green check please. Also, Stevec's answer shows what `sum(n)`s was doing, have a look to it. @P.Jo

Comment: Also, think `count()` function already groups the data inside, based on the columns you use as the inputs, to return n. It is like using group_by and summarise( n() ) but easier. So group_by() isn't needed.